# Update table that Entity Framework doesn't generate dbSet for

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following SQL table structure:

- Table: `ProjectUser` which has a composite pk of `ProjectId, UserId`
- Table: `ProjectUserMember` which has a composite key of `ProjectId, UserId, EmployeeId`

The `ProjectUserMember` table also has FK to the `ProjectUser` table and the `Employee` table.

My problem is that no `ProjectUserMember` `DbSet` is being generated so how do I insert and delete records from the table?

I am unable to do `context.ProjectUserMember.Remove`

Not sure if it helps but here is a snip from the edmx diagram

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get a DbSet from your context like this:

```
Dbset<ProjectUserMember> projectUserMemberDbSet = context.Set<ProjectUserMember>();
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but I get an error that ProjectUserMember is not recognized as an entity.  The Entity Framework doesnt create a dbset for it and it is not part of the diagram.  The diagram shows ProjectUser and then links to Employee.